# How to add multiple input types in single formControl in angular7?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am doing an angular project in which i am using formbuilder. I need to have two input options.
1) select
2) input text box
On selecting option  in select input the textbox will be displayed.

I am having problem with sending the data on submitting the form. The value in textbox is sending undefined or only the input textbox is sending in case of multiple selection.

How to send both the values?

Sample code:-

In **component.html**

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Platform</label>
    <select title="Select" formControlName="platform" class="form-control" multiple data-selected-text-format="count">
      <option value="aws">aws</option>
      <option value="azure">azure</option>
      <option value="on-premise">on-premise</option>
      <option (click)="handleCheck();">Other</option>
    </select>
    <input #item(keyup)="handleOther(item.value);" class="form-control" *ngIf="check" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

In **component.ts**

```js
check = false;
handleCheck() {
  this.check = !this.check;
}

platformOther: string;

handleOther(item) {
  this.platformOther = item;
}
getf() { return this.sampleForm.controls; }

onSubmit() {
  if (this.platformOther) {
    this.sampleForm.controls.platform.value.push(this.platformOther);
  }
  let value = this.f.platform.value.slice();
  const index = value.indexOf("Other");

  if (index !== -1) {
    value.splice(index, 1);
  }

  this.toBe.platform = value.toString();
}
```

This is working. What I have done is I have created an function and on keyup event in the input textbox I am saving that value in a variable in component.ts. and then I am pushing that variable into the array platform.

Can you help me with a more correct way to do this?

Comment: You can only use a FormGroup to combine multiple input types. Otherwise I think its a good idea to create a single `FormControl` for your Input and subscribe to `valueChanges`. To manipulate your value on submit try to use `this.sampleForm.controls.platform.patchValue(<new-value>)` instead